# How to stop a JavaScript program that is being debugged in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, debugging, execution

Ok, I've fired up my debugger in Chrome and I've placed a breakpoint just before an Ajax call to examine the variables on the stack. Hmmm, I notice that one of them is not right. At this point I'd like to stop the JavaScript program from continuing executing (and not making the Ajax request). Is there anyway to do this short of closing the tab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Chrome's Developer Tools you can modify your JavaScript and comment out the part that will trigger the Ajax request. See JavaScript Editing on https://github.com/borismus/DevTools-Lab/raw/master/cheatsheet/chromedev-cheatsheet.png